# VirtualBox no funciona copiar y pegar, ni arrastrar archivos

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

tengo VirtualBox versión 6.1.32 y también instalado el pack de extensiones de la misma. El caso es que mi maquina es un Windows 10 y la maquina que corro virtualmente es Ubuntu 18, he puesto bidireccionalmente la manera de copiar y pegar entre ambos SSOO, y también he instalado el pack de extensiones en linux, y no funciona. ¿Alguien tiene idea que puede estar pasando?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes instalar el Guest Additions desde dentro del Ubuntu 18. En [este enlace](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-ubuntu/) encontrarás instrucciones para hacerlo.  Aunque lo de arrastrar archivos no se si funciona, nunca lo he probado, diria que no, pero lo de copiar y pegar sí.

Comment: Ves a la configuración de la maquina, general, avanzado, ahí deberías de ver las siguientes opciones: - Arrastrar y soltar
- Compartir portapapeles Ahí le das a bidireccional y debería de funcionar. PD: Estoy en la versión 6.1.30

Comment: @masterguru por favor, añade ese comentario como respuesta. De ese modo podrá ser aceptada y la publicación estará completa.